# How can I use Powershell to see which sql server databases have maintenance plans?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to use Powershell to find out which sql server databases have maintenance plans setup, so that I can export this information to a report. I have been using gwmi to retrieve other information that I require for the same report.

I have looked on Google, but can't seem to find anything relevant. I am not a sql server expert, so I am not sure if maintenance plans have files that i could search for or if there is any other way using wmi. I am running the powershell script from a workstation that does not have any version of sql server installed.

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 0):

Maintenance plans are not accessible via SMO, but if they're implemented in SSIS you can look at those packages. Have a look [here](http://www.dbnewsgroups.net/sqlprogramming/t20876-programatically-accessing-maintenance-plans-through-smo.aspx) & [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/3593d7df-4880-43e2-8276-57dd340d1663).

If you've never gotten into this sort of thing before, you probably want to have an experienced DBA walk you through it, at least at first.